# How to get element names with namespace prefix in PHP Xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am using **PHP xpath** to read XML I want to get names of all elements in XML

sample XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" ?>
<main:docs xmlns:admin="someval" xmlns:system="someval" xmlns:links="someval">
    <admin:a someattributes>value<admin:a>
    <admin:b someattributes>value<admin:b>
    <system:c someattributes>value<system:c>
    <links:d someattributes>value<system:d>
</main:docs>
```

I want list of all element names with namespace prefix that is admin:a, admin:b,system:c, links:d

I am using below code

```
$xpath = $xml->xpath('//main:docs/*');

$arr = array();

foreach ($xpath as $child)
{
    $arr = $child->getName();
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($arr);
```

but it returns a,b,c,d without namespace prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each element, you can get the namespaces associated with it.  This is an array such as

```
Array
(
    [admin] => someval
)
```

So you need to extract the first key from this to get the namespace of the element...

```
    foreach ($xpath as $child)
    {
        $arr[] = array_keys($child->getNameSpaces())[0].':'.$child->getName();
    }
    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($arr);
```

Gives...

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => admin:a
    [1] => admin:b
    [2] => system:c
    [3] => links:d
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "someval" values are the real namespaces. "admin", "system" and "links" are only aliases/prefixes in the document. They are optional and can change on ANY element node.

Register your own prefix for the namespace, use the prefix in your Xpath expressions.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" ?>
<main:docs xmlns:main="urn:main" xmlns:admin="urn:admin" xmlns:system="urn:system" xmlns:links="urn:links">
    <admin:a>value</admin:a>
    <admin:b>value</admin:b>
    <system:c>value</system:c>
    <links:d>value</links:d>
</main:docs>
XML;

$xmlns = [
  'm' => "urn:main",
  'a' => "urn:admin",
  's' => "urn:system",
  'l' => "urn:links", 
];

$mainDocs = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($xmlns as $prefix => $namespace) {
  $mainDocs->registerXpathNamespace($prefix, $namespace);
}

$docChildren = $mainDocs->xpath('//m:docs/*');

$array = [];
foreach ($docChildren as $child) {
    $array[] = $child->getName();
}

echo var_dump($array);
```